# How to set posh-git customization variables globally?

Tags: windows, powershell, posh-git, powershell-7.2

I have tried these two:

- `$global:GitPromptSettings.DefaultPromptAbbreviateGitDirectory = $true`
- `$GitPromptSettings.DefaultPromptAbbreviateGitDirectory = $true`

But neither of these changes the value globally. When I open a new instance of PowerShell, the changes are not applied there, the same for VS Code

Useful info:

- I have PowerShell 7.2.1
- I am using Window's Terminal app from Microsoft Store

Any suggestion gratefully received. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put them in your profile file perhaps? Try from your powershell: `notepad $PROFILE`

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen when I run `notepad $PROFILE` I get a dialog stating -- Cannot find `path/to/the/file` Do you want to create a new file?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Can you show the steps for creating a profile to achieve the above goal

Comment: @CuriousLearner It's just a regular script file that'll get executed on startup, there are no "special steps" needed. Just click "yes" the next time you're prompted to create the file :)

Comment: How did you get posh-git enabled if you don't have a profile file?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I have figured out what is happening. the posh-git profile files are in Powershell directory, but the name of the file is different than what should be according to `$PROFILE`. So, when I was doing test-profile, I was getting false.